# Universal links not working with WKWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, ios-universal-links

I have `web-view` based app and other native apps in company. We were using `universal links` to redirect user to other apps when needed (other apps still support `universal links` - I can run them by pressing links from `Apple Notes app`).
We recently made a transition to `WKWebView` (from `UIWebView`), which provides a way better experience. But after the update `Universal Links` stopped working and we cannot start other apps when user press link inside our app.

According to the docs:

> "Universal links let iOS 9 users open your app when they tap links to
>   your website within WKWebView and UIWebView views and Safari pages, in
>   addition to links that result in a call to openURL:, such as those
>   that occur in Mail, Messages, and other apps."

Source:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

It seems that `WKWebView` is not handling the `Universal Links`. My questions is, am I missing some special configuration for `WKWebView` or this is `WebKit` bug? I'm creating web view as provided:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];  
config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;  
config.processPool = // Here I'm using shared process pool  

self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:config];  
self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;  
self.webView.clipsToBounds = YES;  
self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = YES;  

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {  
  self.webView.allowsLinkPreview = YES;  
}  
[self addSubview:_webView];
```

To show the problem I have created simple repository with simple app (https://github.com/apan06/UniversalLinks - with very simple initialisation). There are two web views - `WKWebView` and `UIWebView` with both with simple html that there is only link to `Twitter`. `WKWebView` simply loads the `Twitter` page. On the other hand `UIWebView` open `Twitter` app. Just remembet:
- test it on device with `Twitter` app installed, if you don't have `Twitter app` or don't like Twitter you can change link
- I was testing it on `iPhone 6` with `iOS 9.2.1`

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having this same issue but we are trying to link a web view in our app to other pages/functions without the same app. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a bug in WKWebView that makes it ignore universal links if the navigation delegate is not set. Try setting the WKWebView’s navigation delegate. You don’t have to implement any of the delegate methods.

Comment: I have both WKNavigationDelegate and WKUIDelegate set in iOS9 and my WKWebView is not handling universal links, I'm afraid.