# iOS 8 deep linking not working. App or website's fault?

Tags: ios, twitter

I know the behavior changed between iOS 8 and iOS 9. My app's deep linking works perfectly on iOS 9 & 10. When a user clicks on a special link, a popup appears prompting the user if he would like to open it in the app.

However, for some reason when the user clicks on the same link in iOS 8, the pop up appears but at the same the he is immediately redirected to the app store. (User can actually switch back and tap on the popup and he will be redirected as expected. But the immediate redirect is unnecessary and ugly)

NOTE: It doesn't happen in safari, it happens in Twitter's App. (when a Tweet redirects to a website and the internal browser is used)

I have two questions regarding this issue. First, could it be that something is not implemented in my app? I don't think this is the reason because the popup asking the user to open it in the app is displayed.

Could it be that my website has the wrong code? Since its showing the popup and immediately redirecting at the same time. (but somehow only happens in iOS 8...)

---

EDIT:

I just tested this with Safari, same website, i click on the same link and the app is opened right away (there's not even a popup). So now i'm even more confused.

The place it's not really working at is when I open it through the Twitter's app.

So the flow is Twitter -> Search for tag -> Open Tweet -> Open link to my website -> Tap on the same link as described before.

Could it be that it's actually the Twitter's browser implementation fault?

Comment: Are you using the new Twitter app (v 7+) that opens links with SFSafariVC ? Could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172678/universal-links-not-working-with-wkwebview